# Problems with setting the classpath in ant

Tags: java, ant, classpath

I'm having problems getting my Java program to run (it uses some third party JARs). I can compile it fine but when I call my run target in ant it says it can't find the class that I told it run in the classpath. Here's what my build.xml looks like:

```
<project basedir="." default="build">
<property name="build" value="build" />
<property name="src" value="." />
<property name="lib" value="lib" />

<path id="classpath">
    <fileset dir="${lib}">
        <include name="**/*.jar" />
    </fileset>
    <fileset dir="${build}">
        <include name="*.class" />
    </fileset>
</path>

<target name="build">
    <javac srcdir="${src}" destdir="${build}">
        <classpath refid="classpath" />
    </javac>
</target>

<target name="run">
    <java classname="FirstClass">
        <classpath refid="classpath" />
    </java>
</target>
```

Does anyone know what I might be doing wrong?

---

Here's my stack trace from ant:

```
ant run Buildfile: build.xml

run:
[java] Could not find GuiStarter. Make sure you have it in your classpath
[java] at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.ExecuteJava.execute(ExecuteJava.java:138)
[java] at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Java.run(Java.java:764)
[java] at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Java.executeJava(Java.java:218)
[java] at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Java.executeJava(Java.java:132)
[java] at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Java.execute(Java.java:105)
[java] at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:288)
[java] at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
[java] at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
[java] at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
[java] at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
[java] at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
[java] at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
[java] at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:357)
[java] at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:385)
[java] at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1337)
[java] at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1306)
[java] at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
[java] at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1189)
[java] at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.runBuild(Main.java:758)
[java] at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.startAnt(Main.java:217)
[java] at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.run(Launcher.java:257)
[java] at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:104)
[java] Java Result: -1

BUILD SUCCESSFUL Total time: 1 second
```

Comment: Is the lib directory contained within the src directory?  If you've got a separate src directory being used as the basedir, and lib is at the same level as src, then you'd have to make basedir .. and specify property src as the source directory.  Or you could move your Ant script up one directory.

Comment: Do you use default package in your sources? If not you probably need to include "**/*.class" in your classpath.

Answer (score 5):

I think the problem is with your `classpath` path declaration.  The `build` directory should be a `<pathelement>`

```
<path id="classpath">
    <fileset dir="${lib}">
        <include name="**/*.jar" />
    </fileset>
    <pathelement location="${build}" />
</path>
```

Also, I would only include 3-rd party jars in your `classpath` refid.  So the whole block looks like.

```
<path id="3rd-party-classpath">
    <fileset dir="${lib}">
        <include name="**/*.jar" />
    </fileset>
</path>

<target name="build">
    <javac srcdir="${src}" destdir="${build}">
        <classpath refid="3rd-party-classpath" />
    </javac>
</target>

<target name="run">
    <java classname="FirstClass">
      <classpath>
        <pathelement location="${build}" />
        <path refid="3rd-party-classpath" />
      </classpath>
    </java>
</target>
```

Also, as DroidIn.net has pointed out, you should create a package for you program.

Comment: I agree - I think "pathelement" that's what you use for classes

Comment: With these modifications I'm getting an java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/media/codec/audio/AudioCodec exception instead of a Could not find GuiStarter. Make sure you have it in your classpath error.
I think for this project it would be easier to put the jars in my ant lib directory.

Comment: DON'T put the jars into the ant lib directory.  Looks like the 3-rd party tools have dependency on the above library.  Maybe this will point you in the right direction http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-351989.html

Answer (score 3):

The way it is - only jars inside `lib` directory relative to your path are getting loaded. Do you have all of your 3-rd party jars there? There may be some run-time libraries that you don't need at compile time but which are missing at run time. If you post your stacktrace I'll tell you more :)

Comment: My stacktrace couldn't fit in this comment so I made it an answer to this question.

Comment: Hm - GuiStarter sounds like you have a class that doesn't have a package (is it one of yours?) - in which case you need to make sure your top level directory is in the Classpath also

Comment: Thanks, that was really helpful! Even 3 years later :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this , i could able to run my class.

```
<property name="src.dir" value="src" />
<property name="build.dir" value="build" />
<property name="classes.dir" value="${build.dir}/classes" />
<property name="jar.dir" value="${build.dir}/jar" />
<property name="main-class" value="sample.Sample" />

<target name="clean">
    <delete dir="${classes.dir}" />
</target>

<path id="classpath">
    <fileset dir="${jar.dir}">
        <include name="*.jar" />
    </fileset>
    <fileset dir="${classes.dir}">
        <include name="/*.class" />
    </fileset>
</path>

<target name="compile">
    <mkdir dir="${classes.dir}" />
    <javac srcdir="${src.dir}" destdir="${classes.dir}">
        <classpath refid="classpath" />
    </javac>
</target>

<target name="jar" depends="compile">
    <mkdir dir="${jar.dir}" />
    <jar destfile="${jar.dir}/${ant.project.name}.jar" basedir="${classes.dir}">
        <manifest>
            <attribute name="Main-Class" value="${main-class}" />
        </manifest>
    </jar>
</target>

<target name="run" depends="jar">
    <java classname="${main-class}">
        <classpath refid="classpath" />
    </java>
</target>

<target name="clean-build" depends="clean,jar" />

<target name="main" depends="clean,run" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same problem. To avoid it, I was helped by deleting the "package" line at the very top in the Java code. After that, my VS Studio started complaining that this line was missing, but the xml code was executed successfully)))